# cannot execute commands after starting chrome headless

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome, npm, travis-ci

I am using Travis CI for testing my webpage using selenium. Here is my .travis.yml :

```
sudo: false

language: node_js

node_js:
  - node

addons:
  chrome: stable

install:
  - npm ci

script:
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost:8080
  - npm test
```

The build proceeds correctly, but when it reaches the chrome headless part, it stucks on this:

```
$ google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost:8080
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/4d6aeb8f-eb14-4419-96be-40e270c33ccc
```

It does not further execute the 'npm test' command and so my tests won't run for an eternity. Answers appreciated.

Comment: If you remove `--headless` then it works fine?

Comment: It says `The command "google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost:8080" exited with 1.`, on running tests `(node:6450) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)`

Comment: Please help @Jortega

Comment: So if "non-headless" is not working I would also not expect headless to work. Have you check you version of Chrome matches the chrome driver.exe you are using?

Comment: Yes @Jortega both are the same

Comment: Ok backup one level, can you start chrome without `.travis.yml `? If not what error is returned.

Comment: I did it, by passing the headless argument in the selenium-webdriver of my test.js file.

Comment: See it here: https://github.com/obnoxiousnerd/teddytags/blob/7bbc32cf20eeafa72fe2b8c0b230566fe2fa6c96/test/browser.test.js#L10

Answer (score 0):

Add the headless argument in your test file like this:

```js
var driver = new sw.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(sw.Capabilities.chrome())
  .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().headless())
  .build();
```